# lsass.exe uses 2.4GB of memory when resolving a web page

Tags: windows-server-2008, memory-usage, lsass

I have a user who has been noticing slowdowns with his machine frequently.  When investigating his system (Windows Server 2008 R2) processes, we saw that lsass.exe was using 2.4GB of memory.  A reboot took it back down to 80MB.  It kept happening every day though and today we were able to identify what action he was taking that skyrocketed lsass's memory usage.

All he did was access a web page on another server.  This should only be sending his cert with the web page request, correct?  Why would a local security process care about that?

Does anybody have any idea what might be going on here and how to fix it?

Comment: HTTP or HTTPS site?

Comment: It's an HTTPS site.

Comment: Well, since its an HTTPS site it uses the certificates to set up a SSL tunnel between the two servers. That's probably the reason lsass.exe gets involved, but as to why its consuming that much ram I don't really have an answer :(

Comment: Why is an end user running Windows Server as a desktop OS? You're _certain_ that this machine isn't configured as a domain controller, right?